# Cannot get the key value from JSON Data child object in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm working on angular and try to populate the data from the child object's key value. 
The JSON data is here :

```
"other_lessons": [
    {
        "id": 290,
        "name": "Christmas Test  #290",
        "course": {
            "id": 43,
            "name": "Christmas Test ",
            "description": "",
            "teacher": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Sandy's Teacher",
                "email": "abc@s.com",
                "role": "TEACHER",
                "token": "abcd",
                "about": "Blah blah blah ",
                "phone": "2222222222",
                "image_url": "xyz",
                "payment_information": {}
            }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the details of the data of course.name and course.id. And I' getting this error all the time in my developer console.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/AppTileComponent.ngfactory.js:30)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (vendor.bundle.js:105951)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:105102)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:105445)
at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:105377)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:105103)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:105445)
at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:105377)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:105103)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:105445)
```

What but working fine for the id and name in the JSON data. The code I implemented is like this, I'm passing the details to the selector tag i.e.,

```
<widget-app-tile>
```

**homepage.component.html**

```
<widget-app-block title="You may be interested in">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let lesson of lessons">
    <widget-app-tile [lesson]="lesson"></widget-app-tile>
  </div>
</div>
</widget-app-block>
```

**app-tile.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Lesson } from '../../models/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'widget-app-tile',
  templateUrl: './app-tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-tile.component.css']
})

export class AppTileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() lesson : Lesson = <Lesson> {}

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app-tile.component.html**

```
<div class="content-details">
<div class="details">
  <h5>{{lesson.course.name}}</h5>
  <img class="icon" src="/assets/images/logo-transparent.png" alt="No Internet" align="right"/>
</div>
```

As you can see that if I call the **{{lesson.course.name}}** it throws up an error but when I call this **{{lesson.name}}** or **{{lesson.id}}** it works fine and shows up the data.

I have used the [Cerialize Library](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize#serializing_objects) and my model class is this :

model.ts

```
import { deserialize, deserializeAs, Deserialize } from 'cerialize';

/* UTILTY METHODS */

export function cast(data, modelClass) {
  return Deserialize(data, modelClass)
}

export function castCollection (collection, modelClass) {
  return collection.map( item => cast(item, modelClass))
}

/* MODELS */


export class Course {

  @deserialize id: number
  @deserialize name: string

}

export class Lesson {

  @deserialize id: number
  @deserialize name: string
  @deserializeAs(Course) course : Course
}
```

So this is the model which I'm using to get the data, not using interfaces.

**EDITS**

I have tried getting the results on my home page itself and the results are coming fine, but in using but I don't know why the **app-tile.component.ts** is not working fine. The ocde which I implemented is as  follows :

**homepage.component.html**

```
<div class="" *ngFor="let lesson of lessons" >
#{{lesson.id}} - {{lesson.name}}; Course: {{lesson.course.name}}
</div>

<widget-app-block title="You may be interested in">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let lesson of lessons">
    <widget-app-tile [lesson]="lesson"></widget-app-tile>
  </div>
 </div>
</widget-app-block>
```

And here it is working fine. And one more details are as follows :

**homepage.component.ts**

```
export class MyClassesComponent implements OnInit {

  lessons : Lesson[] = []

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.http.get("/ui/student/home").subscribe( data => {
      this.lessons = castCollection(data['other_lessons'], Lesson)
    })
  }
```

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: can you please remove <widget-app-block title="You may be interested in"> for now and try its working or not

Comment: can you pleas AppTileComponent  class as i given in my answer

Comment: udpated answer with some tips you can use to find out problem next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to formate date in anugla you can make use of angular date piple : https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe here given more format or you can pass formate string according to your self , one of the example for angular site

```
<p>The hero's birthday is {{ birthday | date:"MM/dd/yy" }} </p>
```

---

Its good issue got resolved but for future I suggest you make use of `|json` pipe that can help you to find you are getting object or not and also you are getting proper data or not

and also make use of `?` operator for checking null values so you will not get error at runtime for ex. in you code in binding `{{lesson?.course?.name}}`

---

make code like this and try

```
export class AppTileComponent implements OnInit {
    private _lesson : Lesson;

     @Input()
     set lesson(less: Lesson) {
       this._lesson = (less) ||  new Lesson();
     }
     get lesson(): Lesson{ return this._lesson ; }  

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your both the suggestions and it was not working out since lesson is an Array so I have tried doing this `@Input() lesson : Lesson = Array<Lesson>();` and I was getting this error `Type 'Lesson[]' is not assignable to type 'Lesson'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Lesson[]'.` and when I implemented for a class that is `@Input() lesson: Lesson = new Lesson();` it gave me the same error cannot read property "name". And tried using the interceptor method and still no luck same error cannot read property "name"

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - updated have try..as its array you need to access it by using index or make use of *ngFor of angular

Comment: Sorry, same error that is **Type 'Lesson[]' is not assignable to type 'Lesson'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Lesson[]'.**. I have tried doing this `@Input() lesson: Lesson = new Lesson()` but now no heading is coming up.

Comment: My confusion is that how it is fetching the lesson.id and lesson.name and why not lesson.course.name or lesson.course.id?

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - updated my answer have a look and update things according to it..check the class structure also

Comment: I have edited my question and just look a the new edits and yes I have tried it now it is not even fetching the **{{lesson.id}}**

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - why are you using Cerialize Library that is not needed in angular ...you just have to use function vname.json() this will create object for you ...

Comment: Making my work easier nothing else. I've tested it on the home page and everything is working fine. Just check my edits to my question

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - from where you are getting this json...getting from server response ???...if possible can you please share code on plunker

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - can you please check what are you receiving over here : modelClass..when you do this ...collection.map( item => cast(item, modelClass))

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - if you dont know than put this line export function castCollection (collection, modelClass) {  debugger;
  let coll:any= collection.map( item => cast(item, modelClass)); return coll;
}

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - for now can you please remove this "<widget-app-block title="You may be interested in">"

Comment: I have removed that and it doesn't make any difference

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - can you please share code at jsfiddle or plunker ..where i can see

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - also let me know that you updated your component as i given you or not ...i.e. as per my answer

Comment: I have resolved the issue and the solution was in the homepage.component.html itself. Since I was not passing any value to the `<widget-app-tile>` in the Starting Now and Coming Soon it was showing me the error. The value need to be passed. And I have made changes in my app-tile.component.ts that is `@Input() lesson: Lesson` only worked for me

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma - ha ha ..and you not shared your file ..thats y i told you to share full code ...any ways it ok ...one more thing you can make use of ? operation in html to avoid error ex. lesson?.course?.name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160954/discussion-between-alok-kumar-verma-and-pranay-rana).